# sudo npm install -g node-inspector error

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed node JS  in linux virtual machine on my windows. The problem is I can't use npm like npm install -g node-inspector. But I think the error is because of my node version. My node JS version is 0.10.35. I tried below one. but it still doesn't work.
The error message 
***gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "~/.node-gyp/0.10.35"***

```html
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you are getting?  (posting the actual error message you are getting would probably be good)

Comment: The error message 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/tulga/.node-gyp/0.10.35"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468404/gyp-warn-eacces-user-root-does-not-have-permission-to-access-the-dev-dir)

Answer (score 0):

You installed `node` v0.10.35 in a Linux virtual machine.  Assuming that node still works, here's how you can fix your npm.

`curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

This should get you a working `npm`.

However, the error you report sounds more like a problem with `node-gyp` and building native addons.  If you are getting an error while running `npm`, please upload the `npm-debug.log` to https://gist.github.com and post a link to the gist in the `npm` issue tracker at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues.

Thanks!