# gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir

Tags: node.js, permissions, npm, root

Trying to

```
sudo npm install protractor -g
```

and the same notorious error/warning again (googled to no avail):

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.node-gyp/0.12.0"
```

What seems to happen is that `node version 0.12.0` is downloaded and rebuilt, again and again during the same installation, despite of being the current node version on my machine:

```
node -v
v0.12.0
```

Questions:

- The directory "/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.node-gyp/0.12.0" is actually missing! Why such a misleading message?
- Why was this directory not created neither during the `node v0.12.0` nor during the previous successful rebuild with `node-gyp`?
- (Obviously) How can I prevent this from happening?

I run Mac OSX 10.8.5 if that is of any importance.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

UPDATE. There is a better way - changing `npm`'s default global directory to user sub-directory to which you already have correct permissions, so no need to mess with system file's permissions or ownership in first place.

As recommended in
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions:

> 1. Make a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

> 2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

> 3. Open or create a `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` etc) file and add this line (at the end of the file):

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

> 4. On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

**or** `source ~/.bash_profile`

See also Sindre Sorhus's guide on the topic: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

---

Have now figured what was wrong:

The directory had wrong permissions - it was not **writable** (which would have been a better error message than "accessible").

And because it was not writable, a temporary directory was used and deleted after every use, which is why the whole download had to run again and again.

The solution is to set user permissions with

```
sudo chown -R $USER <directory>
```

and never `sudo npm` again.
It seems whenever you run `sudo npm`, all subdirectories created get wrong permissions, which will lead to problems later on.

[See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787215/1614973).

Answer (score 27):

Try with:

sudo npm install -g *module* **--unsafe-perm**

Comment: No, you don't  `sudo npm` -- see my answer!

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I could not implement the answer above, for some reason.

Comment: for me this worked. ran npm on root so needed to make sure it it could run as root. --unsafe-perm. Thanks for the fix

Comment: Also mentioned at pkg doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport/v/7.0.2

`if you're going to use sudo or root to install Node-Serialport, npm will require you to use the unsafe parameters flag.

sudo npm install serialport --unsafe-perm --build-from-source`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you do not have a folder in this directory "/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.node-gyp/0.12.0".

Just create a new folder named 0.12.0 **which is the version number of your node**

It will fix the problem.

Comment: 2 years later, encountering this problem with node 9.0.0 and of course I don't have a directory `/usr/local/js/node-v9.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/9.0.0` because that's what the install script is supposed to be handling. That's what it is for after all. Instead, I get a "does not have permission" error and an infinite loop during install. The feel of the 90s. Clownish.

Comment: Well, the `mkdir` broke the installer out of its loop. On to the next problem.