# Node-gyp Connect-mongo on Amazon AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-ec2, node-gyp, connect-mongo

I can't get connect-mongo to install on my EC2 instance. Has to do with node-gyp not having access to "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.40" - which is stange because the installed Node version is 4.2.1.

The folder "/root/.node-gyp/" doesn't even exit on the system. So why is node-gyp looking there?

When configuring the server I first installed Node 0.10.40 and then upgraded to 4.2.1.

How can we point node-gyp to the right directory? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Log from **successful** install on local host:

```
$ node --version
v4.2.1
$ npm --version
2.14.7

$ npm install connect-mongo --save
|
> kerberos@0.0.16 install /Users/username/Sites/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
connect-mongo@0.8.2 node_modules/connect-mongo
├── depd@1.1.0
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
└── mongodb@2.0.47 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.20)
```

Log from **failed** install on EC2 Linux:

```
$ node --version
v4.2.1
$ npm --version
2.14.7

$ sudo npm install connect-mongo
\
> kerberos@0.0.16 install /home/ec2-user/apps/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/0.10.40"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/ec2-user/apps/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/apps/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
In file included from ../lib/kerberos.cc:1:0:
../lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/apps/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/apps/adserver/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.16
connect-mongo@0.8.2 node_modules/connect-mongo
├── depd@1.1.0
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
└── mongodb@2.0.47 (readable-stream@1.0.31, es6-promise@2.1.1, mongodb-core@1.2.20)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-139 adserver]$
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as well. I even used these commands (http://pastebin.com/8jWeMZUV) in my config.

Comment: So did it work for you then? Or still stuck?

Comment: still stuck, what i do is rebuild the environment everytime

Comment: Also no luck here. I will try and remove connect-mongo from my project. Just too damn hard and nowhere to find any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried asking Amazon forums or support? Someone told me to try installing libkrb5-dev package in the server itself.

Comment: Tried installing libkrb5-dev but I don't think this package is available using the yum package installer. Have no idea how to install it.

Comment: If you install `node-gyp` globally it fixes the problem... I'm trying to make an ami that is already set up but I still trying to figure out how eb does the node stuff. Did you find a better solution?

Comment: Okay, sounds promising! Will try it out and report back.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. I installed node-gyp globally and then running npm install connect-mongo. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `gyp WARN EACCESS ...` message.  This is just a warning, npm can continue with a workaround. But to get rid of this warning message see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468404/gyp-warn-eacces-user-root-does-not-have-permission-to-access-the-dev-dir).

The problem lies with:

```
./lib/kerberos.h:5:27: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
```

I found this [link](https://github.com/christkv/kerberos/issues/21#issuecomment-145459843) and the solution (on Ubuntu/Debian) appears to be:

```
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```