# Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Tags: node.js, npm, meanjs, npm-install

Having this issue when using npm install. (lots of other people had this issue aswell with other commands/tasks).

I'm adding this question as a reference to a solution that has already worked for quite a few people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

russfrisch commented 4 days ago:

> I was experiencing this same issue.  Changing in the version for
>   grunt-node-inspector to prepend a ">=" instead of a "~" got this to
>   work for me.

Link to [github page](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-debug/issues/7#issuecomment-154450807) where I found this solution.

Comment: I am attempting to install sqlite3 and encountering this issue. In my case, where would I make this change?

Comment: my friend! Thanks for posting this. Saved my hair!

Comment: I had the same issue and this resolve my problems. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Worked here, too, although I changed my package.json from `"grunt-node-inspector": "~0.1.5"` to `">=1.0.0"`, which is the latest version as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, what worked for me was upgrading node

[updating nodejs on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04#41196107)

I am replicating solution from the above link below

To update, you can install n

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Then just :

```
sudo n latest
```

or a specific version

```
sudo n 8.9.0
```

Then try and install

```
sudo npm install <package>
```