# updating nodejs on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I was recently going through the version of node in my ubuntu 16.04 when `node -v` command was used it shows me version 6.9.1 but when `nodejs -v` it shows 6.9.2 previously before using this commands `npm update` command was used.

Now what's these difference in `node -v` and `nodejs -v`? and how to update to the latest LTS version of node/nodejs?

Answer (score 392):

To update, you can install n

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Then just :

```
sudo n latest
```

or a specific version

```
sudo n 8.9.0
```

Comment: You can also use `sudo n current` or `sudo n lts` if you want more guarantee of stability and don't need the latest bleeding-edge features.

Comment: @thund I upvoted your comment, but actually `sudo n current` does not exist, I think you mean `sudo n stable`

Comment: For security reasons I would write `sudo n lts`

Comment: Excellent, sudo n current this also do the same :). Thank you all.

Comment: @Enrique : Did you install "n" with npm first ? what's your distro ?

Comment: With this solution only node version got updated and not nodejs version, how to get latest versions for both ?

Comment: If I refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457834/what-is-the-difference-between-node-vs-nodejs-command-in-terminal node is just a symbolic link for nodejs. 
You start your application with the node or nodejs command ?

Comment: this didn't work for me! it still installed only node8 in my ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram If you ran another version earlier, that old version is likely cached in your shell. Two ways: (1) use the full path (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/node`) or (2) try `hash node` which should reset the cache for the `node` command. You can also open a new shell, log out and back in, or reboot.

Comment: using this way you will install a new version of node but you won't remove the old one, thus, using `sudo node` will refer to the new version, and `node` will refer to the old one

Comment: Does this work if I install `n` on Windows?

Comment: @JimRaynor according to this issue : https://github.com/tj/n/issues/511 it could work. I think you should try !

Comment: hash -r on bash to view latest version

Answer (score 211):

According to [official docs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) to [install node on Debian and Ubuntu based distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md):

**node v12** (Old)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**node v14** (For new users: install this one):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**node v15** (Current version):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Other older versions:**
Just replace the desired version number in the link above.

**Optional:** install build tools

To compile and install native packages

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

To **update node** to the latest version just:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

To keep **npm** updated

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

To find out other versions try `npm info npm` and in versions find your desired version and replace [version-tag] with that version tag in `npm i -g npm@[version-tag]`

And I also recommend trying [**yarn** instead of npm](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)

Comment: That installed `10.21.0` for me instead of 14 ;c

Answer (score 35):

Using [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm):

**Install it:**

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

**Test your installation:**

close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and run:

```
command -v nvm
```

**Use it to install as many versions as u like:**

```
nvm install 8              # Install nodejs 8
nvm install --lts          # Install latest LTS (Long Term Support) version
```

**List installed versions:**

```
nvm ls
```

**Use a specific version:**

```
nvm use 8                  # Use this version on this shell
```

**Set defaults:**

```
nvm alias default 8        # Default to nodejs 8 on this shell
nvm alias default node     # always use latest available as default nodejs for all shells
```

Comment: Working solution

Comment: I spent few hours trying to install Node 16 on my Ubuntu 14.04.6 using `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -`. This Solution works fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Use [n module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

```
sudo n latest
```

Undo :

sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n

Answer (score 14):

Use `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs` to upgrade node (and [only upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/44124) node) using the package manager.

The package name is `nodejs`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130296/4578017 for details.

You can also use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) to install and update node.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then restart the terminal, use `nvm ls-remote` to get latest version list of node, and use `nvm install lts/*` to install latest LTS version.

`nvm` is more recommended way to install or update node, even if you are not going to switch versions.

Answer (score 4):

Difference: When I first installed node, it installed as 'nodejs'. When I upgraded it, it created 'node'. By executing node, we are actually executing nodejs. Node is just a reference to nodejs. 
From my experience, when I upgraded, it affected both the versions (as it is supposed to). When I do nodejs -v or node -v, I get the new version.

Upgrading: npm update is used to update the packages in the current directory. Check https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

To upgrade node version, based on the OS you are using, follow the commands here https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Answer (score 4):

Please refer nodejs official site for installation instructions at the following link

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Anyway, please find the commands to install nodejs version 10 in ubuntu below.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Replace the version(latest 10) you want to install here(setup_8.x)

Answer (score 4):

**node** and **nodejs** are two different packages in Ubuntu software, node is an up-to-date snap package, whereas nodejs is an older version of apt package

to **update** to the latest LTS version of node:

1. Install NVM on Ubuntu 22.04|20.04|18.04 with the command:

> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh

> bash install.sh

2. After the installation, source the profile:

> source ~/.bashrc

3. Verify the NVM installation:

> nvm -v

4. Install Node.js 18 LTS on Ubuntu 22.04|20.04|18.04 as shown:

> nvm install v18

5. Install the latest version using the command:

> nvm install node

6. Once complete, verify the installation:

> node -v

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Edit or create the file :nodesource.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Insert this text:

> deb     https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main
>
> deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main

Run these commands:

```
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -


sudo sh -c "echo deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x cosmic main /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

Update latest version Nodejs :

1. sudo npm cache clean -f
2. sudo npm install -g n
3. sudo n stable

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
source ~/.profile
nvm ls-remote
nvm install v9.10.1
nvm use v9.10.1
node -v
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and got the issue during upgrade node js. The current LTS version is 16.14.2 According to the [NodeSource Node.js Binary Distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) document

Node.js v16.x:

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

if you still get the issue you can also try the following:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get update
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js Current:**

It's work for me..

## Using Ubuntu

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

## Using Debian, as root

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing problem while going to install react app, so i found the solution,

```
npx create-react-app shodkk
```

First install the npm latest version using

```
sudo npm install -g npm@8.4.1
```

So to install the  node 16.x you need to go terminal and type

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Doing this you install the node LTS that is 16.14.o at the time of writing this post.

Try this 2-3 times, also do the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then Now install the package using

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

At last this helps you remove any unwanted package, that remains after updating that is depreciated and need not be there, So use autoremove command.
sudo apt autoremove

So if like the post, Upvote and motivate me to write more, thanks, givingBack to the Community.

Answer (score 1):

First run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

If not working then just run:

```
nvm install v18
```

Answer (score 0):

Use n module from npm in order to upgrade node
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use
sudo n latest

To undo:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n