# Getting error laravel 5.4 vue js setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I run the command `npm install`.
After that running command `npm run watch` but giving following error in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal.

```
> @ dev /var/www/html/lara-vue
> npm run development


> @ development /var/www/html/lara-vue
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/var/www/html/lara-vue/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let path
= require('path');
                                                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at requireConfig (/var/www/html/lara-vue/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:96:18)
    at /var/www/html/lara-vue/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:109:17
    at Array.forEach (native)

npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-58-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development" npm ERR! node v4.2.6 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress
--hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
--progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules
--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     /var/www/html/lara-vue/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-58-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev" npm ERR! node v4.2.6 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     npm run development npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR!     /var/www/html/lara-vue/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: try update nodejs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: what does this have to do with laravel or vue?

Comment: Thanks, nodejs updation solve my problem