# Angular CLI won't install on Ubuntu 16.04 / Node v4.2.6 / NPM 3.5.2

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, and decently new to AngularJS(4) and the Angular CLI as well. I have used the program with Windows 10, and now I am trying to install it on Ubuntu.

When I try and install, whether it be:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli
```

(ERROR + when I try to create a new app)

```
    npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
eddietal2@eddieslaptop:~$ ng new eddie
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

---

or

---

```
sudo apt install  @angular/cli

sudo: unable to resolve host eddieslaptop
```

(ERROR)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package @angular
```

it won't install. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have **an old version of node**. So update your **node version to latest one**.

Using **nvm** you can easily update it. Below is the command.

```
nvm install NEW_VERSION --reinstall-packages-from=OLD_VERSION
Eg. nvm install 7.10.0 --reinstall-packages-from=4.2.6
```

**Then**

Run command `nvm use 7.10.0` to use updated version. And if you want to uninstall old version then run command `nvm uninstall OLD_VERSION`.

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196107/2012446