# can't install latest version of node.js

Tags: node.js

i tried a lot to install latest version of `nodejs` and i followed instruction in their website here [Installing Node.js via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

i have ubuntu 16.04LTS operating system.
when i try this command

```
nodejs -v
```

to check version i installed.i expected it will be 9.9.0
but i found it is v4.2.6
i also tried this command `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`
but the result still the same.
so how can i install the latest version of nodejs

thanks for all of you

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install from apt-get, you found in repo and you will install the latest version in repo. I think that install nvm is the best option:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

you can easily change the node version =)

Comment: i followed [this answer]https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196107/6479099
but now what is the difference between this two commands 
~$`nodejs --version`
v4.2.6
~$`node --version`
v9.9.0

Comment: @Mohammedhakeem I think that the user added other repo with the last node version =)

Answer (score 0):

You can find good tutorial on [godady site](https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-nodejs-ubuntu-17395). Install latest version by using a PPA and just replace '9' by '7' in add repository like below command

> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -

then go forwards to update apt-get and install nodejs.