# How to upgrage node in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, upgrade

I couldn't install node version 4.7 in Ubuntu , when i upgrade the node it shows node 4.2.6 already in newest version.
I need to install npm , only  node 4.7 or above will allow to install npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updating nodejs on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this...

```
Upgrading to the latest stable version

This will update you to the latest available stable version:

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
Upgrading to the latest LTS version

Node also offers a long-term support (LTS) version. If you need that version (or any other), simply specify the version number you want:

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 4.4.2
Checking your Node version

To see which version of Node is currently installed, simply run:

node -v
```

Comment: My node version is 4.2.6, npm is supported only in  4.7 or higher version. So i couldn't use the commands as you suggested.

Comment: Can u pls list the commands u used from starting with necessary outputs