# not able to install polymer-cli in ubuntu 14.04 using npm

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, polymer

command i used 'npm install -g polymer-cli'

'npm config list' returns this

```
; cli configs
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig /root/.npmrc
strict-ssl = false

; builtin config undefined
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE - use /etc/npmrc instead. = true
globalconfig = "/etc/npmrc"
globalignorefile = "/etc/npmignore"
prefix = "/usr/local"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/nodejs
; cwd = /root
; HOME = /root
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

git --verision
1.9.1

node --version 
v0.10.25

npm --version 
1.3.10

problem: polymer --version says

> polymer command not found

i want install polymer

these are the errors i got

```
npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "@babel/helper-optimise-call-expression"
npm ERR!     at ensureValidName (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:284:15)
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:199:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:29:38
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at normalize (/usr/lib/nodejs/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:28:15)
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:310:33)
npm ERR!     at then (/usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:124:33)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/read-package-json/read-json.js:234:40
npm ERR!     at fs.js:268:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-119-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "polymer-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
```

Comment: why did i get a negative vote? please explain

Comment: any help would be good, if u need any extra data please ask

Answer (score 0):

this could be a problem due to incompatibility between the npm version and the package you try to install, which is `polymer-cli`. You are using extre old version of all those packages. I suggest you run an update on all packages: `node`, `git`, `npm`.

#### Updating `node` - [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04):

- Install `n`:

`sudo npm install -g n`

- Then run:

`sudo n latest`

#### Updating `npm`:

- Run:

`sudo npm install -g npm`

#### Updating `git` - [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579589/upgrade-git-version-on-ubuntu-14-04):

- Run these commands in order:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install git
  ```
- Then, check the version of the installed Git:

`git --version`

- It's not always necessary to remove the existing Git before upgrading it, but if you run into any problems, do the following and then repeat the steps mentioned above:

`sudo apt-get remove git`

When you're all one with these, try `npm install -g polymer-cli` again and send me your result.