# Node JS - Not able to install node js version 8.9 or greater in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have tried various methods by which I can install the latest version of nodejs on my operating system but was unsuccessful.

In the end it always ends up installing 
**version v.4.2.6**

When I run the commands below, it always shows an error as shared in the screenshots of my terminal.
**Current release:**

sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -

**or LTS release:**
sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

// throws error
Version:
[image]

Trying to execute node 11 script:
[image]

o/p of the above script: 
[image]

Please guide me how can it be fixed. I have followed some of the other stackoverflow links but couldn't make it.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install nodejs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommand uninstalling your current NodeJS version and install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) instead.
Then you can manage all node version with nvm.

**Method 1:**
I followed this link and it was successful:
[updating nodejs on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**Method 2:**

You can either skip above link and follow the below steps:

**Using Node Version Manager (NVM):**

Install it by following instructions [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation)

**Test your installation:**

close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and run:

```
command -v nvm
```

Use it to install as many versions as u like:

```
nvm install 8              # Install nodejs 8
nvm install --lts          # Install latest LTS (Long Term Support) version
```

**List installed versions:**

```
nvm ls
```

**Use a specific version:**

```
nvm use 8                  # Use this version on this shell
```

**Set defaults:**

```
nvm alias default 8        # Default to nodejs 8 on this shell
nvm alias default node     # always use latest available as default nodejs for all shells
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have npm installed -

run

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

install n globally

```
npm i -g n
```

then switch to the latest stable node version using n

```
n stable
```