# How to update node version 8.12.0 to 10.x?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed node js version 8.12.0 in ubuntu 16.04. Now i need update node version 10.x.

I have tried with this

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

But still got the same version of node. How can i update node version?

Comment: Looks like there's other questions similiar to this here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions?rq=1
and here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195952/updating-nodejs-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Okay, Thank you for response

Comment: How did you install the version `8.12`? What does `which node` show?

Comment: Thank you for response. I have solved it