# npm installation with firebase functions

Tags: android, firebase, npm-install

i faced this error while i trying to install npm using cmd on windows 10

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.6.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.6.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MANA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-21T07_27_36_499Z-debug.log

NPM install failed, continuing with Firebase initialization...

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!
```

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463945/node-pre-gyp-install-fallback-to-build-failed-during-meanjs-installation-on